# ExtendedData is not visible on the popup of the object in the globe of Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

ExtendedData datatable is no more visible on the popup of the object in the globe of Google Earth, is it normal ?

i would like to show the datatable in the description tag popup

Comment: Is there a description element for the placemark in your KML? Trying removing the description and see if the extended data table shows up. Otherwise paste a snippet of your KML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If no description is present in a KML placemark then the extended data will be formatted into an HTML table with one row per data item with the name in the first column and the value in the second.

If a placemark has a description element then the extended data will not be visible.

This KML placemark has both a description and extended data. The text of the description `this is an example` will appear in the popup balloon in Google Earth. The description element overrides display of the extended data.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Club house</name>
    <description>this is an example</description>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="city_district">
          <value>123</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="population">
          <value>40000</value>
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
</Placemark>
```